# I have ported the contents of OpenGL (webGL) to Metal and have a question

Tags: ios, metal

I have ported the contents of OpenGL (webGL) to Metal and have a question.
When doing the following in OpenGL (webGL),

-I want to bind and render the framebuffer in OpenGL (webGL).

```
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FLAMEBUFFER, buffer[0].framebuffer)
gl.useProgram(…)
gl.enableAttribute(VBO, Location, attStride)
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, IBO)
gl.uniform2fv....

gi.drawElement(gl.TRAIANGLES,..., gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0)
```

What if you want to do the same with Metal? It's a rudimentary question, but I'd be happy if you could tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not really a frame buffer concept in Metal. You can render to any texture that has `renderTarget` usage. You can get a texture from a `CAMetalDrawable` (which you can get from a `CAMetalLayer`), or you can create one yourself, using `MTLDevice.makeTexture` method and passing the appropriate `MTLTextureDescriptor`.

Then, when you want to render into it, you need to create a render command encoder, which you can make from an `MTLCommandBuffer`. You will need to pass an `MTLRenderPassDescriptor`. In that descriptor, you can set the texture along with it's load and store actions in the appropriate render target slot (there are 8 of them).

There's actually a WWDC talk that goes in depth on how to port GL apps to Metal: [Bringing OpenGL Apps to Metal](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/611/)

Comment: Thank you.
I noticed that I should look at the item of off screen rendering. It was very helpful.